# add in front of last internalFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlayeredpane

I am using Java Swing. I am adding internal frames with the help of menus in layered pane.

Whenever a new layer (another new internal frame) is added in it, it goes to the back of all frames. Can you please tell me how to bring the newly added jInternalFrame to top of all exsisting internal frames on a jLayredPane.

Thanks!

Comment: Does [`moveToFront()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#moveToFront%28java.awt.Component%29) not achieve the stated effect?

Comment: how exactly do you add the new layer/internalFrame?

Comment: Why a question asked in 2012 will get a vote down in 2014 even when it was answered and accepted long ago :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
myLayeredPane.moveToFront(newlyAddedInternalFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks c24w for the answer, it is correct.

I managed to get another thing to work this around:

```
try { ab.setSelected(true); } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.append(ex.toString()); };
```

Comment: Presumably, where `ab` is the jInternalFrame to bring forward?  You can achieve the same effect with `ab.toFront()`, as Adam mentioned previously.